# Joomla y tableau

Tags: joomla3

Estoy tratando de insertar en un artículo código de un tablero que se encuentra en public.tableau.

El código java y el iframe me los borra cuando le doy grabar.  Alguien sabe cómo pegar el código del tableau a un artículo de joomla? tableau utiliza las etiquetas  o tal vez usando etiquetas ? (las iframe tambien me las borra

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos formas de solucionar.
1. En configuración global revisas el editor y quitas las etiquetas prohibidas, entre ellas iframe, applet, script. Con esto ya puedes pegar los iframe que necesitas para que muestre tableau.

2. Cambias el editor de TinyMCE a None, No tener editor te permite pegar el código de tableau en su totalidad.